# Нужна помощь/совет в адаптивной верстке + owlcarousel

Tags: html, css, owl-carousel

Есть примерно такая структура сайта,  поведение блоков примерно соответствует нужному результату, кроме последнего.

В определенный момент 3 блок уходит в низ и занимает ширину в 100%. Внутренние блоки располагаются в ряд с одинаковой шириной, но при уменьшении экрана контент в синих блоках не помещается, поэтому я добавляю к этому блоку(3) класc карусели(owlcarousel). Вот здесь возникает проблема, если сменить ориентацию устройства на горизонтальную 3 красных блока становятся в ряд, но синие блоки теряют свой вид из за того, что owlCarousel навешивает сверху свои стили и блоки.
Как добиться нужного результата для разной ориентации устройства сохранив при этом структуру и нужный вид страницы?

P.S. Вариант не использовать слайдер это на крайний случай, так как отображение синих блоков 3/1, 2/2 вряд не очень подходит.

Структура и поведение(Адаптив) блоков схожи с нужным резултатом, бутстрап, высота и бордер для лучшего отображения.

```css
.block
{
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
.block__inner
{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="block col-sm-6 col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="block col-sm-6 col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="block col-sm-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="block__inner col-sm-3 col-md-6"></div>
      <div class="block__inner col-sm-3 col-md-6"></div>
      <div class="block__inner col-sm-3 col-md-6"></div>
      <div class="block__inner col-sm-3 col-md-6"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

При смене ориентации экрана добавлять или удалять стили `css` это нормальная практика. Функция `addClass` на `jquery` добавит нужный стиль при смене экрана.

```
 $( window ).resize(function() {
      if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){
            // здесь код для портретной ориентации
            $(".block__inner").addClass("new_view");
            // также можно через css
            //  $(".block").css("");
        }
    });
```

Еще один [вариант](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_events_orientation.asp) для `landscape` и `portrait`

```
$(document).on("pagecreate",function(event){
  $(window).on("orientationchange",function(){
    if(window.orientation == 0)
    {
      $("p").text("The orientation has changed to portrait!").css({"background-color":"yellow","font-size":"300%"});
    }
    else
    {
      $("p").text("The orientation has changed to landscape!").css({"background-color":"pink","font-size":"200%"});
    }
  });                   
});
```

Возможно будет полезным событие смены ориентации экранов `jquery`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on("pagecreate",function(event){
  $(window).on("orientationchange",function(event){
    alert("Orientation changed to: " + event.orientation);
  });                     
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>The orientationchange Event</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>Try to rotate your device!</p>
    <p><b>Note:</b> You must use a mobile device, or a mobile emulator to see the effect of this event.</p>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Footer Text</h1>
  </div>
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

для `css` есть синтаксис для ориентации экрана (возможно будет полезен):

```
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
  #toolbar {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/* For landscape, we want the tool bar stick on the left */

@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
  #toolbar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 2.65em;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

Comment: Вы не совсем меня поняли, здесь высота прописана для наглядности. Проблема в в том что слайдер навешивает свои блоки и стили, которые мешают нормально отображаться моим правил для адатива.

Comment: как вариант переписать стили, те что мешают, своими. Или на крайний случай удалить их из `bootstrap.css`.

Comment: Не совсем, так как под этим блоком идет слайдер который использует эти же стили.

Comment: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/ может создать два блока, в одном отключить, переписав стили, а в другом оставить как есть. Использовать `.hidden-sm` а в другом `hidden-md hidden-lg` будет два дива для разных экранов

Comment: Возьму на заметку, но не хотелось бы грузить лишним кодом страницу. Уточню, бустрап брал для примера. Но, это не столь важно.

Comment: У меня был случай когда создал три разных блока для  `hidden-md` `lg`  и `sm`. Мне кажется `@media screen and (orientation: landscape)` должно работать.

Comment: Есть ещё один нюанс, эти блоки генерируются с рандомной информацией из базы. Поэтому если сделать так, то будет разная информация при разной ориентации.

Answer (score 0):

Не используйте bootstrap на дивы-члены карусели. И для более тонкой настройки отображения используйте опции объекта owl-carousel, коих там тьма.
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html